# Python - Splitting numbers and letters into sub-strings with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, split

I am creating a metric measurement converter. The user is expected to enter in an expression such as `125km` (a number followed by a unit abbreviation). For conversion, the numerical value must be split from the abbreviation, producing a result such as `[125, 'km']`. I have done this with a regular expression, `re.split`, however it produces unwanted item in the resulting list:

```
import re
s = '125km'
print(re.split('(\d+)', s))
```

Output:

```
['', '125', 'km']
```

I do not need nor want the beginning `''`. How can I simply separate the numerical part of the string from the alphabetical part to produce a list using a regular expression?

Comment: Are you going to run into stuffs like `kg*(m^2)/(s^2)`?

Comment: @nhahtdh Most likely not.

Comment: @nhahtdh, surely `J` or `Nm` would suffice for that :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Sorry, what are those?

Comment: @paxdiablo: Sure, but not as simple for `m/s^2` (acceleration).

Comment: @Jacob: Unit for energy, `J` or `kg*(m^2)/(s^2)`, or `N*m`. It is also equivalent to `W*h`, which is used to measure electrical consumption (usually `kW*h`, kilowatt hour).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What's wrong with `re.findall` ?

```
>>> s = '125km'
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+', s)
['125', 'km']
```

`[A-Za-z]+` matches one or more alphabets. `|` or `\d+` one or more digits.

**OR**

Use list comprehension.

```
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'([A-Za-z]+)', s) if i]
['125', 'km']
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'(\d+)', s) if i]
['125', 'km']
```

Comment: What if the number had decimals, is there a way to handle that case? say 1.25km how can I get ['125', 'km']

Comment: `re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)`

Answer (score 1):

Split a string into list of sub-string (number and others)

**Using program:**

```
s = "125km1234string"
sub = []
char = ""
num = ""
for letter in s:
    if letter.isdigit():
        if char:
            sub.append(char)
            char = ""
        num += letter
    else:
        if num:
            sub.append(num)
            num = ""
        char += letter
sub.append(char) if char else sub.append(num)
print(sub)
```

**Output**

```
['125', 'km', '1234', 'string']
```