# How does list comprehension work in this code block?

Tags: python, regex, list, split, list-comprehension

In the code block below, I understand that s is the string. re.split() will generate a list of split results and the list comprehension will iterate through every result created.

I don't understand how "if i" will work here.

This is from the following stackoverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290501/11292262

```
s = '125km'
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'([A-Za-z]+)', s) if i]
['125', 'km']
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'(\d+)', s) if i]
['125', 'km']
```

Comment: Just removes empty items resulting from `re.split`

Comment: `if i` will make sure that no empty match will be retained in the list. Basically `if i` returns false if `i` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty strings evaluate to `False`. Note what happens when we take the `if` out:

```
import re
s = '125km'

print(re.split(r'([A-Za-z]+)', s))
print(re.split(r'(\d+)', s))
```

Output:

```
['125', 'km', '']
['', '125', 'km']
```

The `if` is used to remove the empty string, which is unwanted, per that question. Note that the capture groups in both expressions are needed to ensure that [the part of the string split on (value or unit) is also returned](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).

Comment: Ah okay, great, this makes sense!

I assumed you'd have to write if i = '' or something. Is "if variable" something that's baked into python as a function?